# LDAP test environment

Tags: ldap

what's the best way to develop with ldap without having the connection to the productive ldap server. Can you recommend some software?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747561/ldap-server-for-developer

Answer (score 3):

I'd say a test instance of  [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're more into the Microsoft space, you could also check out:

[Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897400.aspx) (AD LDS)

which is a Windows service based subset of the full AD. You can spin up multiple instances of AD LDS and since it's a Windows service, you can also turn it off when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of LDAP server you have in production. Usually it's a question "AD or not AD?"

If your productions server is AD then it would be either virtual machine with a domain controller or a local instance of AD LDS (formerly ADAM).

If your production server is a generic LDAP server then there is a wide set of options. These days I would use a virtual machine with any Linux and OpenLDAP or/and Fedora Directory Server, or a local instance(s) of ApacheDS or OpenDS.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to install/host/configure a Microsoft Server with Active Directory, you can use the following for LDAP testing purposes:

https://documize.github.io/ad-ldap-test-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try

`https://github.com/Upekshe/simple-ldap-server`

Its running a nodejs server, highly configurable, supports both ldap and ldaps

Dokerized version
`https://hub.docker.com/r/upekshejay/simple-ldap-test-server`